Can a tensor with dtype uint8 be used for a loss function, which will later call '.backward()'?
I attempted to calculate the loss between a tensor with dtype float32 and another with dtype uint8.
Since the loss function performs automatic type promotion, I didn't make a type conversion explicitly at first.
Here's the code:
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

a = torch.randn(3, 3, dtype=torch.float32, requires_grad=True)
b = torch.randint(0, 256, (3, 3), dtype=torch.uint8)
loss = nn.MSELoss()(a, b)
print(loss.dtype)
loss.backward()

The output:
torch.float32

From my point of view, that means the auto type promotiom works as expected.
However, an error occurs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.../test.py", line 8, in <module>
    loss.backward()
  File "/root/.../python3.8/site-packages/torch/_tensor.py", line 522, in backward
    torch.autograd.backward(
  File "/root/.../python3.8/site-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py", line 266, in backward
    Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(  # Calls into the C++ engine to run the backward pass
RuntimeError: Found dtype Byte but expected Float

then I changed the line about loss:
# loss = nn.MSELoss()(a, b)
loss = nn.MSELoss()(a, b.to(torch.float32))

It works.
But why?
I also noticed that in the definition of 'b', I can't set requires_grad=True, since it will raise an error:

RuntimeError: Only Tensors of floating point and complex dtype can require gradients

I think maybe there's some connection with my main problem, so I'm including it here.
So, can a tensor with dtype uint8 be used for a loss function, which will later call .backward()?

The answer is "sort of". Integer tensors can be used in loss functions such as in loss functions for categorical outcomes (see here for an example). However, they cannot be used as a parameter to be optimized. That's because derivatives with respect to integers are not well defined. The derivative captures the effect of an infinitesimal change in the input on the output. But infinitesimal changes are not applicable to integers; the smallest possible change is 1 (or -1).
